# NSMutableArray removeAllObjects issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5, nsmutablearray, xcode4.2

I'm facing a problem with `NSMutableArray` that give me a `Exc_Bad_Access` without a reason.

I have a `UITableView` that contain around 700 records, i wanna to activate a filter process to it, i'm using the following method to filter the content of the `UITableView`:

```
- (void) filterTableContentWith:(int)_minValue andWith:(int)_maxValue {

       [tableContent removeAllObjects];
       tableContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:originalTableContent copyItems:YES];

       if (_minValue == 0 && _maxValue == 0) {
            NSLog(@"This is mean that no filter is activate here");
       } else {
            for (int x = ([tableContent count] - 1); x >= 0; x--) {
                 if ([[[tableContent objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"price"] intValue] < _minValue && [[[tableContent objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"price"] intValue] > _maxValue) {
                       [tableContent removeObjectAtIndex:x];
                 }
            }
       }
       NSLog(@"tableContent count = %@",[tableContent count]);
       [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

When i'm calling this method, it gives me `Exc_Bad_Access` on `NSLog(@"tableContent count ...`

I think that `[tableContent removeAllObjects];` is releasing the array, but it's unreasonable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` returns an `int`, so change your `NSLog` to:

```
NSLog(@"tableContent count = %d",[tableContent count]);
```

and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to change your NSLog for count with %d, I think the following codes are better than removing contents within your loop:

```
...
} else {
  NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"price < %d AND price > %d", _minValue, _maxValue];
  NSArray* array = [tableContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
  tableContent = array;
}
...
```

Comment: thank you, but `tableContent` is `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionaries`, so, your suggest won't work, again, thank you.